# PuTTY Access denied (but the user does not have a password set)

Tags: windows, putty, imac

So I am trying to log on to my iMac from my PC (they're literally 1 foot away from each other) just to have some fun with commands. This worked until I wiped my mac, (I was doing a serious clean up) after that it would no longer work. I've tried turning back on remote login but it doesn't work at all!

Just in case you need the extra info, before I wiped it it had one user. Afterwards I decided to set up an extra for work. So I now have 2. And I have never had any password on any of these users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the remote login service is running?

Go to "System Preferences" then "Internet & Networking" and click on the "Sharing" icon.
In the list of services, see if the "Remote Login" option is checked and check if your user is in the access list.